# Accessing ivar of an instance of the same class in a class method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Edit 2: In addition to Kurt's solution, there is one more way to do it. Take a look at the end of this page, just before comments: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/

---

Edit: It seems class methods in a class category cannot access private members such as ivars and private methods that are implemented through class extensions.

---

I hope this question is not asked and answered before, but I could not find one as both stackoverflow and Google search spams my browser window with kinds of questions that ask to access an ivar directly from a class method, which is clearly not my intention.

Straight to the problem, I'll provide a piece of code, which summarizes what I'm trying to accomplish:

---

XYZPerson.h:

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject
@property (weak, readonly) XYZPerson *spouse;
@end
```

XYZPersonMariage.h:

```
@interface XYZPerson (XYZPersonMariage)
+(BOOL)divorce:(XYZPerson *) oneOfSpouses;
@end
```

XYZPersonMariage.m

```
+(BOOL)divorce:(XYZPerson *)oneOfSpouses
{
  XYZPerson *otherSpouse = [oneOfSpouses spouse];
  if(otherSpouse != nil)
  {
    oneOfSpouses->_spouse = nil;
    otherSpouse->_spouse = nil;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I first thought that maybe an ivar is not automatically synthesized for a property flagged readonly, but it is indeed synthesized.

So, what paths can I take to get the job done?

Comment: Would simply declaring a setter outside of main .h file be acceptable? So you'd declare, say, the category XYZPerson+FriendMethods and expose a setter in that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Where is `aSpouse` supposed to come from? You aren't providing it, or setting it, anywhere.

Comment: OK, then, what error does the compiler tell you when you try this?

Comment: 'XYZPerson' does not have a member named '_spouse'

Comment: @Tommy It is acceptable as long as I can make that setter method private, i.e. non-visible to other classes. edit: I guess it is doable with a class extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `+[XYZPerson divorce:]` is defined in `XYZPersonMarriage.m`, which is a different compilation unit than `XYZPerson.m` where the rest of `XYZPerson` is implemented.

Because of this, when compiling `+divorce:`, the compiler doesn't know there's an implicitly synthesized `_spouse` variable. For all it knows, the property could be backed by a method `-spouse` that you implemented.

Ways to get around this:

- Move the implementation of `+divorce` into `XYZPerson.m`.
- Don't access ivars directly, but do the work via real methods. They don't have to be part of the usual public interface of the class; they can be exposed via a separate header file that only `XYZPersonMarriage.m` imports. Search for "Objective-C private method" for more discussion on the pros and cons of that pattern.

Comment: If I create a header which includes a XYZPerson extension; import it in XYZPersonMariage.m and implement it there inside a `@implement XYZPerson ... @end` block, I get a linker error.

Comment: ...and what's the linker error? You still need to put the implementation of the "private" methods inside `XYZPerson.m`; that's the only file that can access the object's ivars.